# Parsing object to TS class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TS, and I have a question about initializing classes
Here example of parsing object

```
const myObj = {
    "square": 100,
    "trees": [
        {
            "height": 100,
            "needles": 100500
        },
        {
            "height": 50,
            "apples": 20
        }
    ]
};


class Forest {
    constructor(
        public square: number,
        public trees: (Pine | AppleTree)[]
    ) {}
}

class Tree {
    constructor(
        public height: number,
    ) {}
}

class Pine extends Tree {
    constructor(
        public height: number,
        public needles: number,
    ) {
        super(height);
    }
}

class AppleTree extends Tree {
    constructor(
        public height: number,
        public apples: number,
    ) {
        super(height);
    }

    public getApples() {
        console.log(this.apples);
    }
}


export function initMyClass() {
    const forest: Forest = myObj;
}
```

But here is a compilation error - myObject Type is not assignable to type 'Forest'. How can I parse object to that class?
And how to determine what subclass of `Tree` should be used to parse particular object in array

I tried interfaces, but, maybe not in a right way

Comment: Why use `class`es at all when none of them have any methods?

Comment: @Bergi Of cause they do. I deleted it just for this example

Comment: But they matter. `myObj` does not have these methods, and that's exactly what TypeScript is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer
The code is below:

```
enum TreeTypes {
    PINE = "pine",
    APPLETREE = "appleTree",
}

abstract class Tree {
    @Expose() public height: number;
    @Expose() public type: string;
}

class Pine extends Tree {
    @Expose() public height: number;
    @Expose() public needles: number;
}

class AppleTree extends Tree {
    @Expose() public height: number;
    @Expose() public apples: number;
    
    public getApples() {
        console.log(this.apples);
    }
}

class Forest {
    @Expose() square: number;
    
    @Type(() => Tree, {
        keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
        discriminator: {
            property: 'type',
                subTypes: [
                { value: AppleTree, name: TreeTypes.APPLETREE },
                { value: Pine, name: TreeTypes.PINE },
            ],
        },
    })
    @Expose()
    trees: (Pine | AppleTree)[];

    @Expose() 
    getSquare() {
        console.log(this.square);
    }
}



export function initMyClass() {
    const forest: Forest = plainToClass(Forest, myObj, { excludeExtraneousValues: true, enableCircularCheck: true, exposeDefaultValues: true });
    console.log(forest);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `AppleTree` is not a plain object but rather it contains a public instance method called `getApples`. In JavaScript, you need to instantiate a class for you to get the methods defined in the class.

As the original `myObj` doesn't contain the `getApples`, TypeScript noticed that it doesn't match the `AppleTree` class that you defined, which is why TypeScript complained about the error.

```
class Forest {
  constructor(public square: number, public trees: (Pine | AppleTree)[]) {}
}

class Tree {
  constructor(public height: number) {}
}

class Pine extends Tree {
  constructor(public height: number, public needles: number) {
    super(height);
  }
}

class AppleTree extends Tree {
  constructor(public height: number, public apples: number) {
    super(height);
  }

  public getApples() {
    console.log(this.apples);
  }
}

const myObj = {
  square: 100,
  trees: [
    {
      height: 100,
      needles: 100500
    },
    new AppleTree(50, 20)
  ]
};

export function initMyClass() {
  const forest: Forest = myObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what to do, if `myObj` is going from JSON.parse. I know the structure, but I don't know, what type of `Tree` is going next in array. Is there a way to init all subclass of `Tree` while parsing `myObj`?

Comment: Hi @Krechmer, you can consider adding a `parse` static method in all those classes, where you can call it like `Forest.parse(json)` where you can add logic to detect and instantiate those raw object